# PayPal, MPL and Android

Tags: android, paypal

In my Android app, I am using the MPL library to allow users to pay with PayPal. I am able to make purchases in the Sandbox and everything seems fine. I would like to go live but am confused about a few issues.

First, the PayPal docs refer to to "Classic APIs" and "Adaptive APIs". I have no idea what they are talking about. What is MPL using? Doing a Google search, I find posts like "MPL is based upon Adaptive APIs". Well that sure doesn't tell me much. "Based upon" in my English language doesn't necessarily mean it "is" Adaptive APIs.

The PayPal docs say that you need an API Caller account in addition to the Buyer and Seller account. Yet the code in my app only uses a single account and that is where the payment ends up at. So do I need an API Caller account or not? In the Sandbox accounts, all I see are options for creating buyer and seller accounts.

Comment: I wish you luck with Paypal. They have the worst API and documentation (so confusing as well).

Answer (score 0):

MPL library uses Adaptive payment.
Adaptive Payment allows sellers to use your Paypal merchant(business account) to pay to the buyers. So, if a seller has only a personal paypal account he can use your application, through adaptive payment he will be able to pay to a buyer's paypal account. You can send money to one or multiple receivers.

You will get to know more about Adaptive payment from here:
http://youtu.be/GjEPcf7fvkM

To make your MPL library live, you need a Live Paypal Business account. If you don't have one create it here:
https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/merchant

Then you go to your "My Account > Profile > My Selling Tools"
Click Selling Online > API Access > Update to display the API Access page. If Update option is not there you will see create option. You will get this info in the youtube video link above.
Below is the doc to make your app live:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/

Then you go to apps.paypal.com and then login using your live paypal credentials, and then create an application there. You have to enter description and flow of your app. Once they approve it you will get a "Live App ID". You need to use it in your MPL to make it live.